# What is the OR operator in an IF statement

Tags: c#, conditional-operator

In C#, how do I specify OR:

```
if(this OR that) {do the other thing}
```

I couldn't find it in the help.

**Update:**

My code is:

```
if (title == "User greeting" || "User name") {do stuff}
```

and my error is:

> Error  1   Operator '||' cannot be applied to operands of type 'bool' and 'string' C:\Documents and Settings\Sky View Barns\My Documents\Visual Studio 2005\Projects\FOL Ministry\FOL Ministry\Downloader.cs   63  21  FOL Ministry

Comment: Really interesting, every programmer I've seen starting out (including myself) assumes this is the valid way to do it. Here's to you writing many more if statements. :-)

Comment: @Dested : +1 for noticing that common assumption. It wasn't until I read your comment that I remembered spending two days screaming at some of my first javascript because of the same confusion. Seems like with so many other exception handlers and loose-languages, this very logical assumption would have made it's way into a framework by now.

Comment: I wonder if this is because in English we say, for example, "If your grade is A or B, you've done well," instead of "If your grade is A or your grade is B, you've done well."  It just seems more natural.

Comment: @Anthony, I wonder how many people have tried to think about how many different interpretations one could have for that,e.g. think about if someone wanted to throw a null in there or something that could be viewed as multiple types such as a single character that is a digit that could be an int, char or something else.  Computers and human minds run at different levels of complexity still.

Comment: I think it's because you assume that the == operator was overloaded to work with the list you didn't pass it.

Comment: @JB - or even the amount of human "logic" that  could come into play, like making an OR list that is 6 posibilites deep, or nested ORs like `if(x == 7 || (8 && y < 2))` Do they mean x is equal to 8 && y < 2, or x = to 8 AND x = to y < 2 (if that even makes sense)

Comment: I still make this mistake every once in a while if I happen to go on autopilot.

Comment: The error message indicates that this is a valid construction for other data types, which is potentially even worse. Is `value == 1 || 2` shorthand for `value is 1 or value is 2` or `value is true` - assuming it doesn't decide that a logical OR between integers should return the bitwise 3.

Comment: @Anthony: I would read if(x == 7 || (8 && y < 2)) as "If x equals 7 OR If 8 AND y are BOTH less than 2 return true. Of course it would always be false because 8 is NOT less than 2, unless your counting backwards ;-)

Comment: When I have multiple values to consider, I sometimes use the syntax `if (new[] { "User greeting", "User name", "User login" }.Contains(title))` (optionally breaking it into multiple lines for readability).

Comment: It's kind of fun looking over past mistakes and laughing about them. This one however has more. I still think that there should be an easy way to say `if this equals any of these do this`.

Answer (score 105, accepted):

`||` is the conditional OR operator in C#

You probably had a hard time finding it because it's difficult to search for something whose name you don't know.  Next time try doing a Google search for "C# Operators" and look at the logical operators.

[Here is a list](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6a71f45d.aspx) of C# operators.

> My code is:
>
> ```
> if (title == "User greeting" || "User name") {do stuff};
> ```
>
> and my error is:
>
> Error 1 Operator '||' cannot be
>   applied to operands of type 'bool' and
>   'string' C:\Documents and Settings\Sky
>   View Barns\My Documents\Visual Studio
>   2005\Projects\FOL Ministry\FOL
>   Ministry\Downloader.cs 63 21 FOL
>   Ministry

You need to do this instead:

```
if (title == "User greeting" || title == "User name") {do stuff};
```

The OR operator evaluates the expressions on both sides the same way.  In your example, you are operating on the expression `title == "User greeting"` (a bool) and the expression `"User name"` (a string).  These can't be combined directly without a cast or conversion, which is why you're getting the error.

In addition, it is worth noting that the `||` operator uses "short-circuit evaluation".  This means that if the first expression evaluates to `true`, the second expression is not evaluated because it doesn't have to be - the end result will always be `true`.  Sometimes you can take advantage of this during optimization.

One last quick note - I often write my conditionals with nested parentheses like this:

```
if ((title == "User greeting") || (title == "User name")) {do stuff};
```

This way I can control precedence and don't have to worry about the order of operations.  It's probably overkill here, but it's especially useful when the logic gets complicated.

Comment: This is the answer.  Look at how the title variable is being compared on both sides of the OR, that is what you are missing.

Comment: It is also complicated by it not being easy to search for special characters on Google. Even with quotes.

Comment: Smith325: True, of course if you knew the special characters to search for you'd know the answer to the original question.  :)

Comment: Excellant answer. The way you explained it step by step really helped. It made it very simple. So, if you want to use an if statement as an on/off switch, for off just use if(false) {  }

Answer (score 11):

The OR operator is a double pipe:

```
||
```

So it looks like:

```
if (this || that) 
{
  //do the other thing
}
```

**EDIT:**  The reason that your updated attempt isn't working is because the logical operators must separate valid C# expressions.  Expressions have operands and operators and operators have an order of precedence.

In your case, the *==* operator is evaluated first.  This means your expression is being evaluated as `(title == "User greeting") || "User name"`. The || gets evaluated next.  Since || requires each operand to be a boolean expression, it fails, because your operands are strings.

Using two separate boolean expressions will ensure that your `||` operator will work properly.

```
title == "User greeting" || title == "User name"
```

Comment: It's not illegal ;). But yes, it is superfluous.

Comment: @ChrisF - considering he updated it 12 minutes after he posted it, I haven't had a chance to see it yet.

Comment: == has higher precedence in C# than || http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa691323(VS.71).aspx
This means that it was evaluating the expression as (title == "User greeting") || "User name" which is bool || string. If it was evaluating it as you suggest, the error would be "CS0019: Operator '||' cannot be applied to operands of type 'string' and 'string'"

Answer (score 10):

Just for completeness, the || and && are the conditional version of the | and & operators.

A reference to the ECMA C# Language specification is [here](http://www.jaggersoft.com/csharp_standard/14.11.htm#conditional-or-expression).

From the specification:

> 3 The operation x || y corresponds to
>   the operation x | y, except that y is
>   evaluated only if x is false.

In the `|` version both sides are evaluated.

The conditional version short circuits evaluation and so allows for code like:

```
if (x == null || x.Value == 5)
    // Do something
```

Or (no pun intended) using your example:

```
if (title == "User greeting" || title == "User name") 
    // {do stuff}
```

Answer (score 9):

you need

```
if (title == "User greeting" || title == "User name") {do stuff};
```

Answer (score 5):

Or is ||

And is &&

Update for changed question:

You need to specify what you are comparing against in each logical section of the if statement.

```
if (title == "User greeting" || title == "User name") 
{
    // do stuff
}
```

Answer (score 5):

The conditional or operator is ||:

```
if (expr1 || expr2) {do stuff}

if (title == "User greeting" || title == "User name") {do stuff}
```

The conditional (the OR) and it's parts are boolean expressions.

MSDN lists the C# operators in precedence order here http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6a71f45d.aspx . And the MSDN page for **boolean expressions** is http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dya2szfk.aspx .

If you are just starting to learn programming, you should read up on Conditional Statements from an introductory text or tutorial. This one seems to cover most of the basics: http://www.functionx.com/csharp/Lesson10.htm .

Answer (score 5):

In C#9 we can now use the pattern combinators "or", "and" and "not" as an operator in an "is" condition check.

[See this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/patterns#logical-patterns) for more information.

So your code ...

```cs
if (title == "User greeting" || "User name") {do stuff}
```

... could be directly written as:

```cs
if(title is "User greeting" or "User name") {do stuff}
```

Answer (score 3):

See [C# Operators](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6a71f45d.aspx) for C# operators including OR which is `||`

Answer (score 2):

The reason this is wrong:

```
if (title == "User greeting" || "User name") {do stuff};
```

is because what that's saying is

If title equals the string "User greeting"

or just "User name"  (not if title equals the string "User name").  The part after your or would be like writing

```
if ("User name")
```

which c# doesn't know what to do with.  It can't figure out how to get a boolean out of "User name"

Answer (score 1):

In the format for if

```
if (this OR that)
```

`this` and `that` are expression not values. `title == "aaaaa"` is a valid expression. Also `OR` is not a valid construct in C#, you have to use `||`.

Answer (score 1):

You should use `equal` like

```
if (title.Equals("User greeting") || title.Equals("User name")) 
{ do stuff }
```

Comment: Not required, *unless* you use an overload specifying a comparison. Which may be a good idea

Answer (score -1):

OR is used as "||"

```
 if(expr1 || expr2)
 {
    do something
 }
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use both && or ||

```
if (title == "User greeting" && title == "User name") {do stuff}
```

Answer (score -1):

That was my code too. I solved it like that.

if ((title == "User greeting") || (title == "User name")) {do stuff}

Comment: While correct, this is a very old question that has several good answers. No need to answer it again.

Comment: Your code precisely duplicates the code from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2158618/3744182) by Andy West from Jan 28, 2010. -[From Review](https://stackoverflow.com/review/late-answers/33347319)

Comment: Please don't add "thank you" as an answer. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you will be able to [vote up questions and answers](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/vote-up) that you found helpful. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/33347319)