# How to check if something equals any of a list of values in C#

Tags: c#

[What is the OR operator in an IF statement](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2158580/258482)

I asked this question way back when, and when I got the (very helpful) answer, I thought you should be able to say `if (title == "User greeting" || "User name") {do stuff}`. Now if it isn't obvious why that won't work, please refer to the other question and its accepted answer.

I am wondering, however, if there is a way to give an arbitrary list of strings to check if something equals any of them. Something like `if(Array.OR(title, { "User greeting", "User name" })) continue;` Is there such a thing or am I shooting in the dark? It seems like it'd be rather simple to implement.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

CorrugatedAir's example is pretty good, however you can include it inline if needed.

```
if (new string[] { "test1", "test2", "test3" }.Contains("test1")) Console.WriteLine("it works");
```

And it does work: http://ideone.com/QzbvKV (Thanks Soner)

So my code would look like: `if (new string[] { "User greeting", "User name" }.Contains(title)) Console.WriteLine("title contained");`

http://ideone.com/PYugJu

P.S. Thanks Soner for the link, I never heard of ideone before!

Answer (score 10):

You could try the Contains operator:

```
String[] array = {"One", "Two", "Three"};
if (array.Contains("One"))
{
     //Do stuff       
}
```

Comment: Note that if the number of options is large you should use a data structure that can be more efficiently searched, such as a HashSet.  For small data sets it's not relevant.

Answer (score 3):

More comprehensive and flexible solution honoring string comparisons:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;

public static class StringExtensions
{
    public static bool EqualsAny(this string target, StringComparer comparer, params string[] values)
    {
        return target.EqualsAny(comparer, (IEnumerable<string>) values);
    }

    public static bool EqualsAny(this string target, params string[] values)
    {
        return target.EqualsAny((IEnumerable<string>)values);
    }

    public static bool EqualsAny(this string target, StringComparer comparer, IEnumerable<string> values)
    {
        return values.Contains(target, comparer);
    }

    public static bool EqualsAny(this string target, IEnumerable<string> values)
    {
        return values.Contains(target, StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase);
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
if (title.EqualsAny("User greeting", "User name"))
{
    //do stuff
}
```

P. S. Repeating the words of @Servy: Such solution works fine for a small set of values, for large sets consider using Dictionary, HashSet, etc.

Answer (score 1):

You can use **[Enumerable.Contains()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb352880.aspx)** method on this situation. Plus side of this method is *enumeration is terminated as soon as a matching element is found*.

> Determines whether a sequence contains a specified element by using
>   the default equality comparer.

```
string[] fruits = { "apple", "banana", "mango", "orange", "passionfruit", "grape" };
string fruit = "mango";
bool hasMango = fruits.Contains(fruit);
```

Here is a **[DEMO](http://ideone.com/OvRKgx)**.

Don't forget to add `System.Linq` namespace.

Comment: Thanks for the note about adding the system.linq namespace.