# C# if statement with multiple or conditions not returning expected behavior

Tags: c#, if-statement, conditional-statements, conditional-formatting

I have an if statement that will display a .CSHTML Layout under the following conditions:

```
    @if ((ViewBag.title != "Log in")
    || (ViewBag.title != "Register")
    || (ViewBag.title != "Confirm Email")
    || (ViewBag.title != "Login Failure")
    || (ViewBag.title != "Forgot your password?")
    || (ViewBag.title != "Forgot Password Confirmation")
    || (ViewBag.title != "Reset password")
    || (ViewBag.title != "Reset password confirmation")
    || (ViewBag.title != "Send")
    || (ViewBag.title != "Verify"))
{ Layout markup }
```

When I load the `Log in` page; however, the Layout template appears. Setting a breakpoint shows that the page title correctly corresponds to the `!= "Log in"` condition and no exceptions are being thrown. Just to be sure, I checked my markup against the solution in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2158580/what-is-the-or-operator-in-an-if-statement) and it appears to be fine... Have a screwed up my statement logic somehow and just don't see it?

---

Comment: When the title is `Log in` the first condition is false. All the other conditions are true, hence the layout is set. You should replace the ors with ands.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your condition always evaluates to `true`. Consider following condition:

```
if(value != "A" || value != "B")
```

It's always `true`, because `value` can't be equal to `A` and `B` at the same time.

What you're looking for is `&&`

```
@if ((ViewBag.title != "Log in")
&& (ViewBag.title != "Register")
&& (ViewBag.title != "Confirm Email")
... )
{ Layout markup }
```

Comment: Wasn't making the 'always true' connection. Should have been obvious to me but I'm learning...  thank you.

Answer (score 4):

you want `&&`, not `||` here.  Your logic is faulty, your condition will always be true.

Answer (score 1):

Use the && opreator, in your current state your condition its always true..